# Search Page from CSV File and Select Relative Positioned Radio Button

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, radio-button, imacros

## Summary

I am using iMacros to pull data from a CSV file and input data into the according fields (i.e. *Username, Password, First Name, Last Name, Email, etc*.)

#### The page looks like this:

http://oi58.tinypic.com/2q3uonc.jpg

### Problem

My whole problem is taking the information for the company name from the CSV file, using it to search the page for the specific text, and from that point use relative positioning to allow the macro to check the according radio button next to the table row. The table is dynamic so it will not always be the same. I have a macro to extract the table into a CSV file so I can easily search the company and just use the POS Number off the line in the CSV file for easier Radio Button Checking.(*The extraction isn't as clean as I would like it to be, but that's another question in itself. I can clean it up manually for now. There are unneeded blank spaces in the extract that makes the POS information scrambled and unreliable*.)

> Note: I can also switch to Excel, I kind of wanted to anyways due to
>   organization and being able to cleanly see what data is being pulled.
>   But I am kind of stuck because of compatibility with Firefox.

## Question

***In short my question is this:* What is the best way to search the page for specific keywords from a CSV file and fill the corresponding radio button using relative position or something similar?**

I have discovered that the POS Number for each of the rows in the table are the same as the adjacent radio buttons. I am just stuck at this point. I feel like it possibly can't be done in CSV or the basic iMacros functions. I do have the Enterprise edition, so excel and any programming language will work. I also presume it will take javascript to do what I need it to. But being a newbie at programming I wont know how each language interacts compared to another.

*P.S.*
**If** at all possible I would like to use this macro with firefox, the website has compatibility issues with internet explorer as well as chrome. But I am taking anything I can get at this point.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Blake\Downloads\input.csv
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
FRAME NAME=Detail

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:sUserName CONTENT={{!COL1}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:sPassword CONTENT=Password1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:sNameFirst CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:sNameLast CONTENT={{!COL4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:sEmail CONTENT={{!COL5}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:sPhoneNumber CONTENT={{!COL6}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:sFaxNumber CONTENT={{!COL7}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:bForceUserToChangePassword CONTENT=yes
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:copyRoles CONTENT=yes

TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:{{!COL10}} EXTRACT=TXT
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:enterpriseOid CONTENT=yes
```

### input.csv file

```
#UserID#,#Password#,#FirstName#,#LastName#,#Email#,#PhoneNumber#,#FaxNumber#,#ForcedPassChange?(ie.yes;no)#,#CopyRoles?(ie.yes;no)#,#Destination Company(ie.MALARKEY ROOFING PRODUCTS (MALHIC))see Table of Companies.csv#
ExampleUser,ExamplePass,ExampleFirstName,ExampleLastName,exampleemail@gmail.com,555-555-5555,555-none-none,no,yes,MALHIC
ExampleUser,ExamplePass,ExampleName,ExampleLastName,exampleemail@gmail.com,555-555-5555,555-none-none,no,yes,MALARKEY
```

**HTML for the Table Row**

```
<td class="DetailBodyTableRowEven" style="border-width: 0px 0px 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: white;"> <input name="enterpriseOid" type="RADIO" value="134305050665">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000 BULBS (100HIC)</td>
```

*Due to the information being business intensive I had to edit the pictures for apparent usernames and such. But would upload a edited test page if this question gets any action.*

Thank you for reading my book of a question! I didn't know how to summarize this in a better way due to the nature of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Finally after a week of testing different snippets of code and a whole lot of trial and error!

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:DetailBodyTableRowEven&&TXT:*{{!COL10}}* EXTRACT=TXT
```

I feel like an idiot for even asking the question to begin with now. But the problem is solved :)